# Wix Bootstrappler remove registry keys only on successful Uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I have a Wix Bootstrapper that installs a chain of MSI packages. In one of the MSI's I have a RemoveRegistryKey element that is used to delete the registry keys and its sub tree on Uninstall. The problem I am facing is if the first MSI (containing the RemoveRegistryKey element) in the chain uninstalls successfully, but the second MSI operation fails triggering a rollback. I notice that in case of an unsuccessful installation, the keys are removed - leaving the program in an unstable state. The keys should only be removed if the whole chain uninstalls successfully. What am I doing wrong?